# Mailer sólo me manda correo al úlitmo usuario del bucle each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tengo en el método create el código para llamar a `competition_mailer`, concretamente al método del  cual pongo aquí el código:

```
def startCompetitionPlaoff(competition)
 @competition = Competition.find(competition.id)
 @competition.users.each do |i|
  @user = User.find(i)
  mail( :to => @user.email, :subject => "Start Competition") do |format|
        format.html
  end
 end
end
```

Bien, pues en este código, `@competition.users` es igual a 4. De hecho he comprobado, poniendo `puts @user.name` despues de la declaración de la instancia del `@user`, que recorre los 4, pero el mail sólo lo ejecuta en el último de ellos. ¿Alguien podría ayudarme?

Pd: sé que puedo cambiar `find` por `where`, pero si lo hago así no funciona.

Gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se envía un solo correo debido a que únicamente estás generando el objeto para enviar el correo, pero **no** lo estás enviando; para enviarlo debes utilizar `deliver`, `deliver_now` o `deliver_later`, lo cual seguramente lo haces desde donde llamas a `competition_mailer` (probablemente tu controlador) y, por ende, solo envía el último objeto creado.

Te recomiendo crear un método donde llames `competition_mailer` por cada usuario en lugar de iterar dentro del *mailer*. Este método lo puedes agregar en tu controlador o directamente en tu clase `Mailer` (como método de clase).

En particular mi inclino por la segunda opción (prefiero evitar incluir en el controlador lógica ajena a él); por ejemplo, asumiendo que tu clase `Mailer` se llame `CompetitionMailer` y envíes el correo desde la acción `create` del controlador, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

competition_mailer.rb

```
class CompetitionMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def self.send_start_competition_email(users)
    users.each do |user|
      startCompetitionPlaoff(user).deliver
    end
  end

  def startCompetitionPlaoff(user)
    @user = user

    mail( :to => @user.email, :subject => "Start Competition") do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end
end
```

competitions_controller.rb

```
def create
  # Código para crear el objeto
  CompetitionMailer.send_start_competition_email(@competition.users)
end
```